How to get help with a question with a bad premise
I recently posted Jest not calling inner function as expected. The question was asking about something with an incorrect premise (behavior I thought was normal for the tool was specific to my project). The question was (correctly) closed as not helpful, but  I still need help with the issue. What should I do to get find the answer I need?
Note 1: My question is similar to A Car With Square Wheels but from the side of the person who asked for help.

It looks like you're simply lacking a minimal reproducible example in your post? We can't really help you unless you give us one, the closure reason already links to the page I linked and explains this.

Start by adding more information to the question. Which operating system, which browser (and version), which jest.js version and so on.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I am aware that it is not currently reproducible. If I knew what was necessary to reproduce it then I would know what is necessary to fix it. All I really know that is not in the question is that it is not specific to my machine, because published the branch and a coworker replicated it without any difficultly.

@BDL It has been replicated by me and a coworker (everyone on the project who has tried). I am on a windows machine running chrome, she is on a apple machine, and I thing she is using safari. the issue was the same in both cases, so I think it is somewhere in the config, but I am not sure. I dont know enough about jest to know where to look, and google turned up nothing.

@Lincoln if you can run the code in the question and reproduce the issue, then that most likely points to a dependency version being the culprit. People who would be running it would very likely be running the latest Jest version (as they'd install fresh) and yours might be outdated. Although, there is a risk they tried the code in an existing installation, so they might have had the older version.

In your question you did say "The origonal is long so I striped it down to this. so apparently your actual code is different. You do say that the shared code does demonstrate the issue but are you running that code completely separate from your actual code or are you running it in the same context? Try creating the example from scratch by installing all the dependencies again if you're currently running it in the same context as your actual code.

@VLAZ I ran the code after both npm update to update it and after deleting the entire node_modules folder and reinstalling. jest is new for us (I am setting up the inital tests) so I dont think that is an issue, but I am not sure

@Lincoln when you say "the code" you mean the code in the question or some other code that is not in the question? Can you run the code in the question (with nothing else - in a fresh project, like other people would be running it) and reproduce the problem?

@AbdulAzizBarkat the new tests were created by making a new test file in the same folder. As I mentioned to VLAZ, I nuked the node_modules folder. Are you suggesting to start trying to build a new project to try to find the issue?

Yes create an MRE in a new project, since others can't seem to reproduce your problem check if you can reproduce it in a new project, if you can't it's something specific to your project and its versions / configuration, etc.

Found a way to reproduce it. in jest.config.js include module.exports = {resetMocks: true};. without that line, it works, with that line it does not.

I have confirmed changing resetMocks: true to resetMocks: false works in the real codebase too. the resetMocks does indeed do exactly this. I will write up another answer later to put this in stack overflow. Should I delete the original question, or just edit the original to point to the new question? And should I delete this question or leave this question?

Great! This is what's supposed to happen; you try to narrow the issue down to an example to share, and in the process figure out and solve the problem. I'd suggest deleting both this (as it boils down to "do what the banner says") and the subject question (as it's already in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65092376/3001761).

Strange. When I look at the revision history, the site seems to think that the code block was completely changed by @jonrsharpe's edit, even though it appears identical. It shows the same text side by side, in red and struck out before, green after.

(In side-by-side Markdown view, the code blocks are reported as identical, but not in inline or side-by-side rendered views.)

@KarlKnechtel the full change to a code block thing happens when the language hint changes for the code block (as was the case in that edit). I don't know exactly why, but it just does it. I somewhat assumed it's to re-check the code block, since the language hint could be changed to be wrong. But it's entirely possible that's not really the reason and it's a bug/implementation thing (technically, it will change the rendered HTML to mention a different language in the classes, even if the code is the same and the highlighting might match).

@VLAZ Maybe it detects all the differences in the rendered HTML, decides that the block "changed", and then can't find any changes to highlight in the source?


The question was asking about something with an incorrect premise (behavior I thought was normal for the tool was specific to my project).

This is irrelevant. The "car with square wheels" problem is about how-to questions, when you incorrectly assume something about what the problem actually is, and therefore ask to solve the wrong problem.
That isn't really what's happening here.

The question was (correctly) closed as not helpful

No, the question was closed as "needs debugging details". There is no such close reason as "not helpful".

but I still need help with the issue

Something crucial that you must understand about Stack Overflow: we do not "help with issues" here, no matter how good your question is.
Questions and answers here are for everyone. Therefore, the gold standard for a question about fixing a problem in code is:

the question needs to be about one specific problem;

the code shown needs to directly and simply showcase that problem (be a proper minimal reproducible example);

other people need to be able to make the same error, due to a reasonable and plausible misunderstanding (rather than due to not properly thinking it through or carefully checking for typos);

other people with the same problem need to be able to plausibly find the question (i.e. the title describes the problem and would be found by a plausible search tried by others with the question);

other people with the same problem need to be able to identify the question (i.e. after finding it with a search, it should be clear from reading the question that it's about the specific problem they're trying to solve).


(Also: ideally, if someone asked the same question before but did a better job of it, we route you there instead so you can benefit from the existing answers, and so that new answers - if needed - will all be in one place.)
Such a question, and its answer, are in harmony with the goal of the site, to produce the kind of "library" described in the tour.

What should I do to [fix the question]?

Make sure it meets standards.
In this case, the feedback you got is that the problem is not reproducible from the code. This means that you need to figure out what is actually needed to make the problem reproducible. You should be able to copy and paste the code back out of your question starting fresh (i.e., whatever environment setup is needed for demonstrating the problem, you should be able to explain how to get there from scratch), and run that code in isolation, and see the exact problem that you're asking about happen directly. The code should do only what's needed for that demonstration, and ideally without user intervention (if you're making a GUI, this might be unavoidable).
In your case, the mechanics of your example are actually pretty good. But we should only see the failing case in the example, like:
let moduleFunc = jest.fn((func) => {
  console.log('moduleFunc called');
  func();
});

test('moduleFunc', () => {
  let myVar = false;

  const innerFunc = () => {
    console.log('innerFunc1 called');
    myVar = true;
  };

  moduleFunc(innerFunc);

  expect(moduleFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(myVar).toBe(true);
});

(Unless, of course, the "working" code actually needs to be there in order to reproduce the problem. If you run two pieces of code back to back, and the first changes global state, that could affect the second, of course. Maybe that breaks the second part. Maybe it fixes something that should be reported as broken. Or maybe the second part is supposed to work on the changed state. You're the one who needs to try to reason about this.)
If you think it's useful to show the working code, do that in a separate code block, after explaining why you're doing so (e.g. "I think the above code should do XYZ instead, because I think it's equivalent to the following code that does do XYZ:") and then wrapping that into the question (e.g. "why does changing the code in ABC manner affect the result?).
When you present such an example, don't talk about the differences between the example and your actual code, because we are not concerned with your actual code. We're concerned with the problem that you're asking about, and the question that you're asking about it. Once you have an example that actually demonstrates the problem, and thus an acceptable question, and hopefully eventually an answer to the question, it's once again on you to adapt that answer to your actual code. Because we aren't "helping" you or providing "support"; we're answering a question.
I don't know anything about Jest, and I don't have an environment set up for using it; so I can't really help with figuring out why the example is reproducing for you but not others. Please start by trying it yourself, copying and pasting back out of the question into a new project. Presumably the tests will pass (as they did for others who closed the question) and thus you won't reproduce the problem.
Then, as I said before: you need to figure out a) how this is different from your actual code and b) what difference actually matters - i.e. what causes the problem to reproduce.
From the comments here, it appears that you've already figured this out: there was an issue in your Jest configuration. That might be considered something to close "as a typo", but maybe you (and others) still think there's a legitimate question there that people could ask. Perhaps one of:

What does this resetMocks option do?

Why does using resetMocks: true cause this code to work the way it does?


Either way, you would need to include that information in the question: your "example" includes the config setting as well as the code. Also, either way, it doesn't matter whether you know the answer - or even if you already knew the answer before asking. What matters is whether other programmers could reasonably have the question - whether answering it is useful information to clear up a misunderstanding (or lack of understanding), rather than pointing out an oversight.

"The "car with square wheels" problem is about how-to questions, when you incorrectly assume something about what the problem actually is, and therefore ask to solve the wrong problem." That is exactly what happened here, I was solving the incorrect problem.
